What is wrong with this argument/integration by parts
Assume that $\phi:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and has compact support in $[t_1,t_2]\subset [a,b-1]$, a proper subset of $[a,b]$. Let $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Consider the integral
$$f(x):=\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)^{-\lambda} (\phi^2)^{\prime}(t)\,dt.$$
The steps/statements (1)-(4) below lead to an evaluation of $f$ in $(*)$, the last equation in this question. I claim that $(*)$ can not be true. The question is: which step/statement is false and why ?
Denote by $I$ the interval $(t_2+\delta,b]$, where $\delta>0$ is fixed.
(1) The function
$$x\mapsto\int_{t_2}^{x} (x-t)^{-\lambda}  (\phi^2)^{\prime}\,dt=0$$
identically on $I$, since $\phi$ is supported on $[t_1,t_2]$.
(2) The function
$$x\mapsto\int_{a}^{t_1} (x-t)^{-\lambda}  (\phi^2)^{\prime}\,dt=0$$
identically on $I$, since $\phi$ is supported on $[t_1,t_2]$.
(3) The factor $t\mapsto (x-t)^{-\lambda}$ is smooth
on $[t_1,t_2]$, whenever $x\in I$.
(4) By (1), (2), and (3), an integration by parts gives
$$f(x)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} (x-t)^{-\lambda}d(\phi^2(t)) =
-\lambda\int_{t_1}^{t_2} (x-t)^{-1-\lambda}\phi^2(t)dt,\tag{*}$$
for all $x\in I$.
Now, $(*)$ can not be correct. Why ? because $(\phi^2)^{\prime}=2\phi\phi^{\prime}$ and the product $\phi\phi^{\prime}$ may change sign from positive to negative and from negative to positive (infinitely) many times. So $f$ can be very "small", while the absolute value of the right side of $(1)$ is bounded below by a positive number. There is a stupid mistake here. What is it ?

What are the two initial equation originating with $t_1$ and $t_2$ ? Why are they true ?

I understand the intuition behind your conclusion that (*) cannot be true, but have you tried to actually prove that the two sides cannot be equal, or to check with simple examples whether the equality holds? It doesn't seem obvious to me that the magnitude of $(\phi^2)'$ cannot balance out the cancellations that could come from oscillations.

For example, if you take $\phi(t) = \sin(nt)$ for large $n$, then indeed $(\phi^2)'(t) = 2n\sin(nt)\cos(nt)$ has very fast oscillations if $n$ is large, but there is also a factor of $n$. So if the integral (without the $n$) is of order $1/n$, then the product remains order 1.

@Vincent. I had already tested that for $n=1$ before posting the question. Eq. () failed. But I am still interested in your thought. I will take $\phi(t)=\psi(t) \sin{nt }$, where $\psi$ is smooth with compact support, and estimate both sides of $()$. I don't think that will make any difference because one can rescale things back, but I am curious.
